# user permission for bot

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot, facebook-permissions

I have a question about Facebook permission using a bot, I read on messenger API that we can get some information about user when we make a call to graph api using user id. I found that it doesn't provide his homelocation, email and birthday. Should I have a permission for that or there is another way to get those informations?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/user-profile

Comment: thank you for your reply. I got all those fields but I need to get user_location, user_email and user_birthday so that's why I'm asking if there is a way to get that

Comment: No there is no way to get that as far i know.

Comment: You would need to use Account Linking to make them log into your app and grant it the necessary permission, and then request that info via a call to the normal Graph API `user` endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Those fields require a app-scoped ID and the proper permissions granted by the user. The PSID from Messenger provides a limited subset of user profile data, as @luschn pointed out.